Confused in David Bohm's *Quantum Theory*
In discussing matrix mechanics Bohm says in chapter 16 of Quantum Theory that the $rm$ element of operator $A$, $a_{rm}$, is given by
$$a_{rm} = \int dx\ \psi^*_r(x)A\psi_m(x) \hspace{1in}      (Eqn. 2)$$
He then goes on to discuss the 1D harmonic oscillator specifically.  And he says at the beginning of ch. 16 sec. 4:
$$\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)_{mn}=\int dx\ \psi^*_n(x)\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)\psi_m(x)  \;\;\;$$
Note that the indices in the integrand here are swapped compared to the indices in his Eqn. 2.  AFAICT, this is not just a notation change, but actually has consequences, since two equations down he derives
$$\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)_{mn} = \sqrt{2m}\ \ \delta_{m-1,n}$$
So $x+ip/\hbar$ becomes a raising operator.  But AFAICT if we calculate $(x+ip/\hbar)_{mn}$ consistently with Eqn. 2, we have
$$\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)_{mn}=\int dx\ \psi^*_m(x)\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)\psi_n(x)$$ which evaluates to
$$\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)_{mn}=\sqrt{2n}\ \delta_{m,n-1}$$
and so $x+ip/\hbar$ becomes a lowering operator.
I presume that David Bohm is smarter than I am.  So can someone tell me what I am missing?

I've checked the book: the matrix elements are computed as $\langle n|(\cdots)|m\rangle$ (n is the row index, m the column) and not $\langle m|(...)|n\rangle$ as it is stated, which means that it's probably a typo. Moreover, the final matrix is indeed correct and it's one associated to the lowering operator (e.g. the only non-zero entries belong to the columns to the right of the diagonal )

@Claudio  Thank you!  I also noticed the final matrix.  So it's not just me then.  Thanks.  I can sleep at night once again!  :)


In discussing matrix mechanics Bohm says in chapter 16 of Quantum Theory that the $rm$ element of operator $A$, $a_{rm}$, is given by
$$a_{rm} = \int dx\ \psi^*_r(x)A\psi_m(x) \hspace{1in}      (Eqn. 2)$$

OK. This is fine.

And he says at the beginning of ch. 16 sec. 4:
$$\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)_{mn}=\int dx\ \psi^*_n(x)\left(x+\frac{ip}{\hbar}\right)\psi_m(x)  \;\;\;$$
Note that the indices in the integrand here are swapped compared to the indices in his Eqn. 2.  AFAICT, this is not just a notation change, but actually has consequences...

This index swap appears to be a typo, since it is inconsistent with your "Eqn. 2" above. Either it is a typo or else you are not correctly telling us the analog of $\hat A$ in this context.

So can someone tell me what I am missing?

The matrix elements for the raising and lowering operators are worked out in detail in many references, including online references.
For simplicity I will set $\hbar = m\omega = 1$, and so we have:
$$
\hat a \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\hat x + i\hat p\right)\;,
$$
which is the usual lowering operator, and for which the matrix elements are well known:
$$
a_{nm}\equiv \langle \psi_n|\hat a|\psi_m\rangle = \sqrt{m}\langle n|m-1\rangle = \sqrt{m}\delta_{n,m-1}\;.
$$
It is similarly well known that for the raising operator, we have
$$
a^\dagger_{nm}\equiv \langle \psi_n|\hat a^\dagger|\psi_m\rangle =
\sqrt{m+1}\langle \psi_n|m+1\rangle = \sqrt{m+1}\delta_{n,m+1}
$$

so $x+ip/\hbar$ becomes a lowering operator

Not "becomes," but is. Or, more precisely, is proportional to the conventional lowering operator.
